# How to make hovering over a class to trigger changes in other classes?

Tags: html, css, class, system, vote

I want to make a pure css [no jquery] star rating system. So I have a html form with 5 radio buttons. So far I can make when I hover/click on a star radio button to change it's own background image. It works for every star BUT separately. When I click on the fifth star - only the fifth star is changed. When I click on the fourth star - only the fourth star is changed and so on.
I want to make that when I hover/click on the fifth star -> all stars to change their background image. When I click on the second star the first two stars to change and etc. so the user can see for how much stars he is voting. (you've seen these rating systems all over the internet)

I want to make like these (again only css):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I end up with this:

[image]

So I have 5 stars/radio inputs and each is from a class:

1 star -> radioStarButton1

2 star -> radioStarButton2

3 star -> radioStarButton3

4 star -> radioStarButton4

5 star -> radioStarButton5

```
           <input type="radio" name="stars" id="'.'2stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'" class="radioStarButton2" value="2" />
           <label for="'.'2stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'"></label>

           <input type="radio" name="stars" id="'.'3stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'" class="radioStarButton3" value="3" checked />
           <label for="'.'3stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'"></label>

           <input type="radio" name="stars" id="'.'4stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'" class="radioStarButton4" value="4" />
           <label for="'.'4stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'"></label>

           <input type="radio" name="stars" id="'.'5stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'" class="radioStarButton5" value="5" />
           <label for="'.'5stars-for-id-'.$row['id'].'"></label>
```

I want to make when I hover/click on the second class .radioStarButton2 to change also the fist class -> .radioStarButton1 and THAT is the problem - to change more than one class elements IF it is possible.

Also the css:
This is working css:

```
input[type="radio"]{
display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background-image: url("uncheckedstar.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

.radioStarButton1:hover + label
{
    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.radioStarButton1:checked + label
{
    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

The next code is obviously wrong but I don't know how to do it. I'm uploading it only for an idea what I'm trying to do:

```
.radioStarButton2:hover + label , .radioStarButton1
{

    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.radioStarButton2:checked + label , .radioStarButton1
{
    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

.radioStarButton3:hover + label , .radioStarButton1 , .radioStarButton2
{

    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.radioStarButton3:checked + label , .radioStarButton1 , .radioStarButton2
{
    background-image: url("star.png");
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: You will have to handle it using javascript. Basically using javascript, check which radio button is being hovered/clicked & add a class to required elements for changing background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension of Koen's solution ... and stays after clicked as well ... you need to re-position/style the labels (and add your stars), hide the inputs, but it's CSS only

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f82Fg/2/

HTML

```
<div class="butts">
    <input id="r5" type="radio" class="butt" value="5" />
    <label for="r5">5</label>
    <input id="r4" type="radio" class="butt" value="4" />
    <label for="r4">4</label>
    <input id="r3" type="radio" class="butt" value="3" />
    <label for="r3">3</label>
    <input id="r2" type="radio" class="butt" value="2" />
    <label for="r2">2</label>
    <input id="r1" type="radio" class="butt" value="1" />
    <label for="r1">1</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.butts {
    float: left;
}
.butt {
    display: block;
    float: right;    
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.butt:hover,
.butt:hover ~ .butt,
.butt:hover ~ label {
    background-color: blue;
}
.butt:checked,
.butt:checked ~ .butt,
.butt:checked ~ label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but how can I reverse the selection of the stars. In this example everything works great in my case but in a reverse selection. Any ideas ?

Comment: I managed to reverse them with the solution above - floating them right. Cheers and thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

If you place the HTML elements in reverse order, you can use the CSS sibling selector (`~`) to select the preceding stars.

HTML:

```
<div class="stars">
    <span class="star">5</span>
    <span class="star">4</span>
    <span class="star">3</span>
    <span class="star">2</span>
    <span class="star">1</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stars {
    float: left;
}

.star {
    display: block;
    float: right;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;


    background: grey;
}

.star:hover,
.star:hover ~ .star {
    background: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfHX4/

Comment: Thanks! Your example combined with the examples below did the job! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can only select “to the right” or “downwards” with CSS, not “to the left” or “upwards” – meaning, selecting descendant elements and siblings on the same level after an element in the DOM is possible; selecting ancestors or previous siblings is not.

So what you could do to get the star up to and including the one hovered to change color, is change color of *all* of them when the container element gets hovered – and then make the stars coming after the hovered one be gray again, using the `~` selector.

No for the “active”/radio-button-checked state, there is no easy way to do this – you could try to use the `:target` selector, but that would require the whole stuff to be nested into a couple of elements with different IDs, and it would lose the state again once some other hash-anchor on the page would be used.

To actually achieve that kind of thing, you will have to change the order of the stars, so that the first one *displayed* is the last one of them in DOM order, etc. – for example by floating them to the right within their container element, or by using `direction`.

That way, when the last element gets checked, only that one gets the orange color – and only the first in *visible* order will be orange.
The second-to-last gets checked, you format the second-to-last one and the last one (again using `~`) – and due to reverse display order, the first to stars in visible order will be orange – etc.

The only problem left will be *combining* those two approaches – not exactly sure if that can be done easily.

Edit: OK, after seeing Koen’s answer, it should be quite easy, if you use the reverse-order trick for both :hover and :checked states.

Comment: I dunno, I like the trick of unhighlighting the later ones without hacking order of the semantic markup.

Comment: Yes, but that’ll only work for the hovered state, not for the star chosen via checking the radio button and using `:checked` for formatting – because the container element is not affected by that, so no way to format “all those up to and including the checked one”. Using reverse order will make both hover and checked work with the `~` selector to make the “active” one and its “previous” ones being formatted together.

Comment: And I think semantics is not that big of an issue here – whether you ask a user to rate something on a scale of 1 to 5 or 5 to 1 (what users without CSS and most likely the ones using screen readers would get presented) doesn’t really matter, as long as they are told that 5 means “best” and 1 means “worst”.

Comment: "To actually achieve that kind of thing, you will have to change the order of the stars, so that the first one displayed is the last one of them in DOM order, etc. – for example by floating them to the right within their container element, or by using direction."      -> Floating the right - that did the trick! That was the final piece of this puzzle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could place each `label` in a nested list and apply the hover state to include child elements like you would with a drop-down navigation.

However, you'd still need some scripting to mark any lower-level star `input` fields as selected once a user clicks on a higher-level star anyway. Otherwise, when they move the mouse off, the hover effect would disappear and you'd still have the same issue of only one star is shown as highlighted.